# Close a Window Using pyatspi

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, accessibility

Is there anyway to close a window using accessibility in pyatspi? Using accerciser, I can't seem to find a component for the top bar with the maximize, minimize, and close buttons. Is this possible?

I'm currently working on Ubuntu. I want this to work on any Linux system where the GNOME desktop is used.

Note: I want to tag this with either atspi or pyatspi, but I don't have enough reputation to do that. Can someone do it for me?

Right now, it seems that Alt+F4 closes any window on the GNOME desktop. So I'm trying to simulate the Alt+F4 key combination using pyatspi. I can simulate key strokes by looking at the values in keysymdef.h in Xlib, but I can't seem to use any modifiers.

Is there anyway to generate Alt+F4 using at-spi? Will this solution even work?

Answer (score 3):

I am new to AT-SPI, so please do not treat it as a reference. I didn't find an AT-SPI method either and I send ALT+F4. First line grabs focus (getChildAtIndex() is to traverse from Application to a window). Then goes: ALT down, F4 press, ALT up.

```
app.getChildAtIndex(0).getChildAtIndex(0).queryComponent().grabFocus()
pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(64, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESS)
pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(70, None, pyatspi.KEY_PRESSRELEASE)
pyatspi.Registry.generateKeyboardEvent(64, None, pyatspi.KEY_RELEASE)
```

Comment: Did the application respond to this sequence? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Correction. Works on Ubuntu but not WSL. `wmctrl` returns `cannot get client list properties` in WSL.

Comment: Further clarification. You need to be running X11 not Wayland. I'll write a proper answer when I understand why.